I'm unable to run my python program with oop concept
Can anyone tell me that why the code is only running content under operation_perform and not after it?
import math
class Shape:
  def operation_perform(self):
    m = input('''
      Select the shape:
      1. Select 1 for area.
      2. Select 2 for perimeter.
      ''')
    
    if m == '1':   
      def area(self, a, b = 0):
        n = input('''
        select the shape:
        1. Select 1 for circle.
        2. Select 2 for square.
        3. Select 3 for rectangular.
        ''')

        if n == '1':
          print('area of circle: ', math.pi * self.a**2)
        
        if n == '2':
          print('area of square: ', self.a**2)

        if n == '3':
          print('area of rectangular: ', math.pi * self.a * self.b)

    elif m == '2':
      def perimeter(self, a, b = 0):
        n = input('''
          select the shape:
          1. Select 1 for circle.
          2. Select 2 for square.
          3. Select 3 for rectangular.
          ''')

        if n == '1':
          print('perimeter of circle: ', 2 * math.pi * self.a)
          
        if n == '2':
          print('perimeter of square: ', 4 * self.a)

        if n == '3':
          print('perimeter of rectangular: ', 2*(self.a + self.b))
    else:
        exit()

s = Shape() 

s.operation_perform()

I am getting the output as shown below:
output: 
      Select the shape:
      1. Select 1 for area.
      2. Select 2 for perimeter.
      1  

Why my program is not going inside area() or perimeter() functions? Can't I do this without using constructor?

def is short for define. your code defines a new function name area when the user chooses 1. To execute a function you have to call the function area(). You have to define all the functions out of the condition and inside the condition you just call it

Is this exactly how your program is? because the function definition def area(... is inside your if, which is unusual... anyway, the reason it is not doing anything is that, upon entering those if conditions, there is only a function definition, and no execution of those function. Try to call the function at the end of the conditional branch (at same indent level of the if scope, not inside the function)

@RodrigoRodrigues Thank you so much for explaining my mistake I got the point. :)

There's nothing OO about this - it's just straightforward linear programming with no justification for using a class

@SIGHUP Ohh!!! ok, can you please convert this program using OOP so that I can understand the difference between them or let me know what concept of OO I can add here? Because I also want to know how this program will be more better in terms of Big(O) if I use proper OOP (that I didn't use here in the current approach).

operation_perform Vs operation_performed

The problem is that you are defining the area and perimeter methods inside the operations_perform method, but you are not calling them.
Corrections applied:
Edit: OOP'd
import math

class Shape:
    def area(self):
        pass
    def perimeter(self):
        pass
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
    def area(self):
        return self.side ** 2
    def perimeter(self):
        return 4 * self.side
class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.width)
circle = Circle(5)
print('Circle area:', circle.area())
print('Circle perimeter:', circle.perimeter())
square = Square(4)
print('Square area:', square.area())
print('Square perimeter:', square.perimeter())
rectangle = Rectangle(4, 2)
print('Rectangle area:', rectangle.area())
print('Rectangle perimeter:', rectangle.perimeter())


As @SIGHUP said and I quoted him "There's nothing OO about this - it's just straightforward linear programming with no justification for using a class". Sir, can You answer this how can I use OO to further make this program more better. Or want to know which concept of OO will make it more better?

@傅能杰 Applied some good ol' encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism. Truth is I'm trying to answer your question the most time efficient way for me.  That means that sometimes I won't put in the effort give the most optimal answer, just a working one. From the solution I consider the person asking is responsible to apply the solution to his project optimizing it and adapting it to his needs. Wouldn't mind if you marked it as correct .

If you really want to define a base class holding abstract methods, do it correctly and use the abstract base classes functionality and @abstractmethod. Creating empty methods in a regular class is just bad code.

@l4mpi I want to write an answer to his question, not to give him an ultra-optimized version answer to his question. As stated before, he should do that.

@LaszloHunyadi Thank You sir for solution. I will definitely try to make it more optimized.

@LaszloHunyadi it has nothing to do with optimization, the issue is that your answer contains code that's entirely useless with an implication that this is how you do OOP in python. If you are aiming for a simple solution, remove the Shape class or at least the empty method definitions in it; if you are aiming to demonstrate OOP with a base class, then give a correct demonstration and not something this half-baked.

@I4mpi I got what you are saying. Thank you for your response and concern. With the solution provided by Eran Moshe (above) I got the idea and it is very helpful. Thank you once again for your response.

My friend, this is not exactly a demonstration of OOP concept..
I've allowed my self to refactor the code a bit so you can catch a glimpse of how OOP concept works:
import math
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def perimeter(self):
        """Calculate the perimeter of the shape."""
        pass

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.width + self.height)


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, side):
        super().__init__(side, side)


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        s = Shape()
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
    # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Shape with abstract methods area, perimeter

    rect = Rectangle(3, 7)
    print(rect.area())
    print(rect.perimeter())
    # 21
    # 20

    square = Square(3)
    print(square.area())
    print(square.perimeter())
    # 9
    # 12

We can see that the class Shape is abstract, as Shape doesn't have any particular way to calculate area or perimeter.. But we know every shape in our program should have area and perimeter.
Defining it that way (abstract) means that every other class that will inherit Shape, will have to implement those functions.
So we can see Rectangle, inherit Shape, and implement those 2 functions.
Now when we look at Square, we see the real power of inheritance. We know that Square is a special form of Rectangle. So we see Square inherits from Rectangle. And instead of implementing the functions, it uses it's Parent functions. And we just write a new init for Square, because Square doesn't have x, y. only x.
Here's a little exercise, implement Ellipse, and refactor the Circle class to use the power of inheritance.

Thank you so much for including different OOP inheritance and abstract method. I will definitely try to include the code for Ellipse to understand the inheritance.

You have three shapes. Circle, Rectangle & Square. Each of these is a Shape.
An OO approach to this could look like:
from math import pi as PI
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Area of {self.__class__.__name__} = {self.area():.2f}"

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
    def area(self):
        return PI * (self._radius ** 2)

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side):
        self._side = side
    def area(self):
        return self._side ** 2

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
    def area(self):
        return self._width * self._height

CONTROL = {
    "1": [Circle, ["radius"]],
    "2": [Rectangle, ["width", "height"]],
    "3": [Square, ["side"]]
}

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            x = input(f"{prompt}: ")
            return float(x)
        except ValueError as _e:
            print(f"\a{_e}")

while True:
    for k, v in CONTROL.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v[0].__name__}")
    shape = input("Choose shape (q to quit): ")
    if shape == "q":
        break
    if not shape in CONTROL:
        print("\aInvalid selection")
    else:
        params = []
        c, p = CONTROL[shape]
        for prompt in p:
            param = get_float(prompt)
            params.append(param)
        print(c(*params))

You should use a control structure that defines the class and its associated parameters. Thus your main "driver" code is trivial and any extensions for different shapes just requires a new class and appropriate addition(s) to the CONTROL dictionary. You will notice that the "driver" never directly refers to any of the classes by name

You are creating area and perimeter functions, but never call them.
